# Question on Hierarchial data template in WPF Tree

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF tree which needs to show some nodes. Lets say I have 2 types of entities, EntityA and EntityB. Both these entities implement a common interface IEntity. Now, EntityA will have a collection of EntityB elements as well as EntityA elements. How can I show this via a HierarchicalDataTemplate ?

I am exposing a ObservableCollection() called "DisplayItems" in my VM that will contain elements of  EntityA type.

Both EnittyA and EntityB will have another ObservableCollection called "ItemCollection". For EntityA, the ItemCollection list should ideally contain entities of EntityA and EntityB types.

The current HierarchicalDataTemplate and the XAML that I am using is as follows:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCollection}" DataType="{x:Type Entities:EntityB}">
      <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="compositeCT">
          <Image Source="/Images/EntityB.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
          <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
          <Label Foreground="Black" Content=" = "/>
          <Label Foreground="Blue" Content="{Binding Path=CompositeLabel}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="nCompositeCT">
          <Image Source="/Images/EntityB.png" Width="15" Height="15"/>
          <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCollection}" DataType="{x:Type Entities:EntityA}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Image Source="/Images/ElementA.png" Margin="3" Width="15" Height="15" Focusable="False"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path = Name}" Focusable="False"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView x:Name="tvMyTree"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItems}"
            AllowDrop="True"         
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            Margin="5"
            TreeViewItem.Expanded="OnTreeViewItemExpanded"
            TreeViewItem.Selected="OnTreeViewItemSelected" 
         />
```

Comment: Looks like your xaml code didnt get pasted properly

Answer (score 0):

You can define two HierarchicalDataTemplates you are fine. And in the place of TextBlock you can put whatever complex visualization you need depending on the other Properties of your EntityA and EntityB

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:EnittyA}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:EnittyB}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose ItemTemplateSelector fits perfect to your requirements. ItemTemplateSelector is inherited, so you should not care about endpoint receiver of template. Receiver (item container) just addresses to selector and the last one returns proper template according to DataType:

```
public class LayoutItemTemplateSelectorItem
{
    public Type TargetType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DataTemplate Template
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class LayoutItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public LayoutItemTemplateSelector()
    {
        this.Items = new Collection<LayoutItemTemplateSelectorItem>();
    }
    public Collection<LayoutItemTemplateSelectorItem> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var component = (LayoutItem)item;
        var typeToSearch = component.GetType();

        var foundItem = this.Items
            .Where(i => i.TargetType == typeToSearch)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (foundItem != null)
        {
            return foundItem.Template;
        }

        throw new Exception(string.Format(Properties.Resources.AppropriateTemplateNotFound, typeToSearch.FullName));
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="EntityBTemplate" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCollection}"
                                       DataType="{x:Type Entities:EntityB}">
                ...
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="EntityATemplate" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCollection}"
                                      DataType="{x:Type Entities:EntityA}">
                ...
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <LayoutItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector">
                <LayoutItemTemplateSelectorItem TargetType="{x:Type EntityA}"
                                                Template="{StaticResource EntityATemplate}"/>
                <LayoutItemTemplateSelectorItem TargetType="{x:Type EntityB}"
                                                Template="{StaticResource EntityBTemplate}"/>
            </LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayItems}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```